# writng a for loop to perform same function in files in a folder

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-programming

when I run the function nwc on the file, it works as shown, but I want a for loop to call all the files in the folder to perform the nwc function. It does not work. Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
nwc(nxmar_18)

#$Alloc_Matrix
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     D1    D2    D3    D4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     6     5     0     0
#2     0     5     8     0
#3     0     0     4    15

#$Total_Cost
#    D1
#1 1095
```

**Not working in the for loop. showing this error**

```
cost_aloc <- vector("double", length(mar_18))
for(p in mar_18){
  nxmar_18 <- read_excel(p)
  nxmar_18 <- nxmar_18[, -1]
  cost_aloc[p] <- nwc(nxmar_18[[p]])
  write.xlsx(cost_aloc, file = "out_put_8.xlsx")
  print(cost_aloc)
}
```

> New names:
>   * `` -> ...1
>   Error in -nrow(ex_matrix) : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: What is `mar_18`? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If its a list of paths to the files is that what you want to be using as `p`?

Comment: yes, mar_18 is the list of paths to the files.

Comment: mar_18
[1] "Table-example(10).xlsx" "Table-example(11).xlsx" "Table-example(12).xlsx"
[4] "Table-example(13).xlsx" "Table-example(14).xlsx" "Table-example(9).xlsx" 
>

Comment: So `nxmar_18` is set to (basically) `read_excel(p)` and then you are trying to extract `p` from it as though its a list.  Try  `cost_aloc[p] <- nwc(nxmar_18)`